# Before and after sliders within a slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I'm creating a custom Shopify site using the theme "Debut" and I want to organize the page better and compile all of the before and after sliders into a slideshow.

I used this codepen as a reference for the before and after sliders: https://codepen.io/nosurprisethere/pen/xrXjYV

`<div class="wrapper">`

As you can see from the codepen the second slider action doesn't work either (another issue ... loop?).

I've been working on this site for far too long and would just love some constructive ideas on how to do this properly and efficiently!

Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "second slider action doesn't work either"?

Comment: Sorry about that you're right - I meant if you duplicate the "wrapper" HTML to create a second slider, the slider action doesn't work on the second one.

Comment: Can you update the code like the way you are saying with two wrappers?

Comment: @theWellHopeErr all you'd have to do is copy and paste the entire wrapper div to create a second before and after slider. Once doing that, you'll notice the second before and after slider you just pasted, the functionality doesn't work